# Refresh Div Content (local .html only)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, refresh

I have a very simple html page (used as an info board) that is held locally only. Part of it is the met office widget to display the three day forecast and rainfall radar. Unfortunately the only way currently to update date/info is by refreshing the whole page using either meta refresh option or a user logging in  and refreshing manually. As the widget is the only item that needs to be refreshed is there a way I can refresh the div only? and that this happens after a set amount of time?

```
<div>
    <iframe src="#"></iframe>
</div>
<div>
    <iframe src="#"></iframe>
</div>
<div>
    <script type="text/javascript"> moWWidgetParams = "moAllowUserLocation:false~moBackgroundColour:white~moColourScheme:white~moDays:5~moDomain:www.metoffice.gov.uk~moFSSI:352790~moListStyle:vertical~moMapDisplay:side~moMapsRequired:Rainfall~moShowFeelsLike:true~moShowUV:true~moShowWind:true~moSpeedUnits:N~moStartupLanguage:en~moTemperatureUnits:C~moTextColour:black~moGridParams:weather,temperature,wind,gust,pop~"; </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/public/pws/components/yoursite/loader.js"> </script>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use ajax application

Comment: Like the guy above me said you could use ajax, or you could use a setTimeout to refresh it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ajax and timer. Something like:

```
setInterval(function () {
  $.ajax({
     url     : "specific url",
     method  : "GET"/"POST",
     data    : "",
     success : function (data) {
        $('#divID').html(data);
     } 
  });
}, 500);
```

Some attention about that i am using jQuery here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, as it is local what should the url be?

Comment: The url need to be the page that you need to reach. If the page is on your server you can access it like '~/(pathToPage) '  , but if the page is somewhere in the web, then you will reach it as ' h t t p ://thePageName'. If the request is ' 200 ' which is a code that is telling you the request is OK.Then the ' data ' variable will take the value of the response and then you can do whatever you want with it. You need to learn what HTTP protocol is.